# passing directory with spaces in it from raw_input to os.listdir(path) in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, escaping

I've looked at a few posts regarding this topic but haven't seen anything specifically fitting my usage. [This one looks to be close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36555950/spaces-in-directory-path-python) to the same issue. They talk about escaping the escape characters.

My issue is that I want this script to run on both MAC and PC systems - and to be able to process files in a sub-folder that has spaces in the folder name.

Right now I use this code gleaned partially from several different SO posts:

```
directory = raw_input("Enter the location of the files: ")
path = r"%s" % directory

for file in os.listdir(path):
```

I don't quite understand what the second line is doing - so perhaps that's the obvious line that needs tweaking. It works fine with regular folder names but not with spaces in the name.

I have tried using "\ " instead of just " ", - that didn't work - but in any case I'm looking for a code solution. I don't want the user to have to specify an escape character

On Windoze using sub folder name "LAS Data" in response to raw_input prompt (without quotation marks), I get an message that:

> the system can't find the path specified "LAS Data\*.*"

Comment: does **os.path.normpath** wouldn't work in this case. Asking because just didn't have nothing to do with MAC ever.

Comment: and as I see "LAS Data\*.*" is globing pattern ?

Comment: @Take_Care_ What are you suggesting? I can't understand your comment. Updated my question to show I am typing in "LAS Data" (without quotation marks) in response to raw_input parameter.

Comment: I'm sugesting using **os.path.normpath** function to produce valid path for any system You are using Your script on.

Comment: Where did you get that `path = r"%s" % directory` line? Link?

Comment: It was in some kind of search for using Python to process all files in a folder. I'll see if I can find it again. It seems to add the need wildcard to the folder name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is most likely not with the code you present, but with the input you gave. The message

> the system can't find the path specified "LAS Data\*.*"

suggest that you (or the user) entered the directory together with a wildcard for files. A directory with the name "LAS Data\*.*" indeed does not exist (unless you did something special to your file system :-).

Try entering just "LAS Data" instead.

The raw string should not be needed either

```
> python
Python 2.7.11 (v2.7.11:6d1b6a68f775, Dec  5 2015, 20:32:19) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> directory = raw_input("Enter the location of the files: ")
Enter the location of the files: Directory with Spaces
>>> for file in os.listdir(directory):
...     print(file)
...
hello-1.txt
hello-2.txt
>>>
```

Comment: That's what I am doing - updated my question. I'm thinking the code `path = r"%s" % directory` must be appending "\*.*" to the path so I can get all files ???

Comment: @dbmitch     `path = r"%s" % directory`  cannot append anything, its just simple string interpolation.

Comment: Works fine now without that line - and specifying correct folder name with escape characters or wildcards.Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

> I don't quite understand what the [`path = r"%s" % directory`] line is doing

It creates a copy `path` of `directory`:

```
>>> directory = raw_input()
LAS Data
>>> path = r"%s" % directory

>>> path == directory
True

>>> type(path), type(directory)
(<type 'str'>, <type 'str'>)
```

Really wondering where you got that from. Seems pretty pointless.

Comment: Thanks - it is pointless. Internet copy/paste can create a lot of useless repeatable code